# Отслеживание всех касаний

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, touch-event

Мне нужно отслеживать каждое прикосновение на айфоне, и вроде бы все получилось, но определяется касание только вне кнопок или текстов. ТО есть если жмакать по пустой области то все работает, а если по кнопке, то касание уже не записывается. Кто нибудь может подсказать, как это исправить?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    swiped = false
    if let touch = touches.first{
        force = touch.force/touch.maximumPossibleForce
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        let time = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        print(force,lastPoint,time)
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent!) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available {
                // 3D Touch capable
                force = touch.force/touch.maximumPossibleForce
                lastPoint = currentPoint
                let time = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
                print(force,lastPoint,time)
                self.logToFile(data: "X,Y-\(lastPoint), Forse-\(force) , Time-\(time) \n".description.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо сделать свой подкласс UIApplication и переопределить в нём метод sendEvent(_:):

```
override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
  // делаете что нужно с событием

  super.sendEvent(event)
}
```

После этого необходимо сделать так, чтобы вместо стандартного UIApplication использовался наш подкласс. Для этого переходите в AppDelegate и удаляете строку `@UIApplicationMain` – она генерирует стандартную функцию main, являющуюся точкой входа приложения. Вместо этого мы создадим свой main. Создайте файл main.swift со следующим содержимым:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc,
  UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv).bindMemory(
    to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
    capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
  NSStringFromClass(MyApplication.self),
  NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Здесь MyApplication – это созданный ранее подкласс UIApplication.

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь @DmitrySerov! У меня получилось самому найти почти такое же решение) Мб вы так же можете помочь, как можно вытаскивать конкретные координаты X Y? Но дальше мне еще сложно понять, я могу в sendEvent получать все координаты и сразу их обрабатывать, допустим свайп слева направо, я получу все его координаты, сохраню их, обработаю и передам системе просто наличие свайпа, так вот, как это можно передать в ViewController?